# Django Integrity error for integer fields

Tags: django

I have an integer field defined in models.py. If the value is not entered for it via Admin form then i want it to be stored as NULL.

```
employees = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

I always get IntegrityError NOT NULL constraint failed whenever i try to submit via Admin form for that table. I have made sure that i run migrations using the following commands:

> python3.5 manage.py makemigrations
>
> python3.5 manage.py migrate

Django version: 1.11.4

Comment: Provide full error traceback. Also there is no need for `default=None` when you have already defined `null=True`

Comment: http://dpaste.com/3TD9JV2

Comment: I see you are using `sqlite3` are you sure when you ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` it was on this same database file and not to some other? Try to rerun those commands. Also the error complains about `employees` field in `freshsuccess_accounts` make sure you are adding `null=True, blank=True` in that model field and not to some other employees field in some other model.

Comment: Iam sure that iam running those commands correctly on the default sqlite3 DB and on the correct field. I build my model using http://mmcardle.github.io/django_builder/

Comment: I figured out what was the problem. It was because I added "blank=true" and "null=true" after i already created the databases. I had to delete my db and then "syncdb" and then it worked. Thanks for the help @AamirAdnan